# MySQL JOIN - Don't want NULL Value

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Lets say I have 2 tables:

```
 table1
   table1_id
   table1_name

 table2
   table2_id
   table2_name
   table2_description
   table1_id
```

I join like so:

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table1_id = table2.table1_id
```

How can I have table1_id return its default value instead of NULL when there are no matches in table2?

Answer: Since table1_id exists in both tables, I needed to used aliases.

```
 SELECT *, table1.table1_id AS tid, table2.table1_id AS t2id FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table1_id = table2.table1_id
```

Comment: Left join then coalesce?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean NULL value of table1_id? Left join, table1_id never be NULL. you are select star, only possible null values for table2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you bring in the default row and then use logic in the `select`:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.table2_name, t2def.table2_name) as table2_name,
       . . .
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2def
     ON t2def.table1_id = $defaultid;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT table1.*
  table2.table2_id,
  table2.table2_name,
  table2.table2_description,
  ifnull(table2.table1_id, table1.table1_id) t2id
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.table1_id = table2.table1_id
```

Again, there is no point to check if table2.table1_id is null, as it is the join column ... always either NULL or exactly same as table1.table1_id